# Can I set up PVM in such way that master doesn't start own tasks?

Tags: linux, cluster, parallel-processing

We have a `Perceus` cluster (Warewulf) consisting of 4-core master and a number of 4-core nodes. I can start `PVM` on the master and then add all nodes - it works fine. However, there are other guys who need this master for their tasks, so I cannot overload it. I have tried to start `PVM` on a node, but something goes wrong. First of all, `PVM` console doesn't start correctly - it always freezes the first time I run `pvm` command. Then I cannot add other nodes

```
libpvm [t40005]: pvm_addhosts(): Already in progress
```

But it is not true - I cleaned carefully `/tmp/` and killed all `pvm*` processes left from previous attempts.

So now I have the only way - to run from the master. Therefore I need to set it in such way, that it will not run own tasks, but start tasks on the nodes.

Can you help me with this?

Or may be you know a better place to ask this question?